# Return Record Id of newly created Record After Using NavigationMixIn.Navigate

Tags: lightning-web-components, pagereference, navigation, navigationmixin.navigate

I have created a button in a custom LWC that when clicked, the below js runs.

This opens the standard salesforce new record create modal and the user can then enter information to create a new record.

Because of the navigationLocation : 'RELATED_LIST' once the user hits save, this does not navigate to the new record, rather it stays on the page it was called from (this was intended since its called from the flow and I wanted the user to continue in the flow).

I want to pass the Id of that newly created record back to the flow for use within the flow.

Is there a way to access that Id ??

Thank you!

````
            type: 'standard__objectPage',
            attributes: {
                objectApiName: this.Sobject,
                actionName: 'new'                
            },
            state : {
                count: '1',
                nooverride: '1',
                useRecordTypeCheck : '1',
                defaultFieldValues: defaultValues,
                navigationLocation: 'RELATED_LIST'
            }
          });```
````

Comment: I am searching for exactly the same.

Comment: @Damecek have you found any solution or workaround for this?

Comment: We chose a different approach, using `record-form` and lwc quick action to have `record-form` embedded in a modal.

Comment: Cool, thanks for sharing. I ended calling a local JS method after the navigation that called an auraEnabled apex method which queried the record that was just added based on latest created date as well as some other unique information.

Comment: Yes, we were thinking about this approach as well, but the other option looked safer.